# catching a promise error wrapped into an observable - angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

One of the methods in an angular service returns an Observable that a component is subscribed to. But in that method there is a promise that is returned as well and I want to be able to catch that in case it returns a reject. Find piece of code below:

```
return this.http.get(url)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .map((data: any) => {
                try {
                    if (data === "14") {
                        this.nativeService.set(value)
                            .then(() => {
                                console.log('ok');
                            })
                            .catch((err) => { throw new Error(); //error that I want to catch
                            })
                    }
                }
                catch (err) {
                    throw new Error();
                }
                return data;
            })
            .catch((err) => this.handleError(err));
```

This nativeService is currently mocked which returns the following

```
set(value: any): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reject('');
    })
}
```

The data is returned though. Then the error is thrown and I am not being able to catch it in order to call the method handleError(). I understand that promise is an asynchronous call. Can someone advise on how to re-arrange the code in order to catch an error returned by the service.

Thanks,
Ashley

Comment: is it `set(value)` or `set(data)` ?

Comment: @suraj yes set data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how you return a data from an observable. You cannot use a simple `return data` kind of statement here. Also you are already returning an observable so where do you expect this data will go?

For data to be returned you actually create a new observable and put an observer on the received data.

Let me correct your code:

```
return Observable.create((observer) => {
 this.http.get(url)
 .map(res => res.json())
 .subscribe((data) => {
   if (data === "14") {
     this.nativeService.set(data)
     .then(() => {
       console.log('ok');
       observer.next(data);
     })
     .catch((err) => {
       observer.next(err); // Error thrown if some problem in promise.
     })
   }
  },(err) => {
    observer.error(err); //Error thrown if problem in http.get().
  });
```

Now the component you have subscribed from will have 3 outputs. 1. data 2. Promise error (Both of 1 and 2 in `.subscribe`'s data) and 3. `http.get()` error. Accordingly you have to manage there.

**NOTE:** I have solved only the problem mentioned in question. I am not sure about the part that I do not know like -

1. `if(data === "14")` - Here it seems like you want to compare it with number 14 and not string "14".
2. What does http.get() result? If it returns a single number value then it's fine.
3. `this.nativeService.set(data)` - Assuming this promise returns everything correctly.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try it out.

Comment: Thanks, your code gave me the start point to solve my particular problem :-)